# Detect if plugin is installed in browser

Tags: javascript, php, html

On [my site](http://soseek.org) I am using a search browser plugin.
On the bottom on the site it has an object to add the browser plugin to your browser.
This content will be displayed if the plugin is **not** installed.
But if the plugin is installed the content shouldn't be displayed.
I have auto-load Javascript code that should check if you have the plugin installed.
If true than the the content should be hidden. But it doesn't work. `var isInstalled` is always `0`.

This is my Javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javscript">
    function check () {
            var isInstalled = extender.IsSearchProviderInstalled("http://www.soseek.org?q=x%s");
            if (isInstalled) {
                document.getElementById("s_button").style.visibility = "hidden";
                document.getElementById("l_button").style.visibility = "hidden";
            }
    }
</script>
</head>
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I've found docs about *IsSearchProviderInstalled* and it only works in InternetExplorer 7+ and is used this way:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function IsInstalled () {
            if (window.external && window.external.IsSearchProviderInstalled) {
                var isInstalled = window.external.IsSearchProviderInstalled ("http://www.dottoro.com");
                if (!isInstalled) {
                    window.external.AddSearchProvider ("searchProvider.xml");
                }
            }
            else {
                alert ("Your browser does not support the IsSearchProviderInstalled method!");
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="IsInstalled ()">Add search engine if not installed</button>
    <br /><br />
    To manage search engines, open the drop-down menu of your browser's Search Box (Firefox and Internet Explorer)
    or select Options/Basics/Default Search/Manage (Google Chrome).
</body>
```

Source: http://help.dottoro.com/ljfslnsp.php

Comment: And gives a other Method fpr Firefox or Chrome ?